# Free default daily limit, datastore google app engine for paid apps

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, billing

do i get 50 thousand free writing operation if I enabling billing, according to this picture that taken from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=iw
I can't see that:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [billable limits](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Billable_Resource_Quotas), where it says:

> Every application gets an amount of each resource for free, but application administrators can increase these quotas by enabling paid apps and setting a daily budget. You will be charged for the resources your application actually uses, and for the amount of resources used above the free quota thresholds.

So yes, you get 50k free write ops per day.